# Can I add a referenced JButton to a second JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, reference

Basically, i have a button that works fine within one panel. I want the exact same button to display concurrently in another JPanel and react to the same actionlistener etc.

Comment: Have you tried it? You could save us some time if you tried it and posted the results.

Comment: yes i have. I can get around the "problem" fairly easily. There are a number of ways to achieve the same result. I am just wondering if it is technically possible to add a "reference" and what the syntax would be for such a thing. oh, and the result when trying brute force is that it "steals" the object for itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A component can only belong to a single parent, so you cannot add a button to two or more containers.

You can, however, use a `ActionListener` on multiple buttons.

A simple solution would be use an `Action`.  An `Action` is a self contained unit of work, it carries with it the configuration details and `actionPerformed` handler.

You could create two separate instance of the `Action` and apply it to two different `JButton`s and get the same visual details and they would carry out the same work when triggered...

See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering. That seems like a fine solution but is there no way to simply reference an Object in Java even though it belongs to another object?

Comment: Not unless you have a reference to the parent object AND the parent object provides you with access to the child object - Be careful of what looks like a "simple" solution, these have a nasty habit of exploding when you least expect them to.  Easy and right aren't always the same thing, especially in an OO environment. That doesn't mean the solution needs to be complex though ;)

Comment: He can have "..two separate instances of the Action" that's true, but he can have only one ;)

Comment: @nachokk Yes, you can, but I was highlighting the fact that you don't have to, thus breaking need for some kind of reference chain...